# Python and PiCamera Color Detection Boolean Issues

Tags: python, opencv, colors, detection, picamera

I'm fairly new with Python and trying to code a way a PiCamera to pick up on different colors and react based off of that. My current attempt for each color is to take a picture and detect the color involved. Some example code is below.

```
def red_detect():
    # initialize the camera and grab a reference to the raw camera capture
    rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(640, 480))

    # allow the camera to warmup
    time.sleep(0.1)

    # grab an image from the camera
    camera.capture(rawCapture, format="bgr")
    image = rawCapture.array

    # Convert BGR to HSV
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    lower_red = np.array([161, 155, 84],np.uint8)
    upper_red = np.array([179, 255, 255],np.uint8)
    red_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)
    red = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=red_mask)

    return 255 in cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)
```

and then that code will be evaluated with an if statement such as
`if green == True:`

However, all of my colors are coming back as True. Am I approaching taking a picture wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you just wanna detect the color of image, there are easier method to do:

```
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open('image.jpg')

w, h = image.size

pixel = []

for x in range(w):
    for y in range(h):
        r, g, b = image.getpixel((x, y))
        pixel.append([r, g, b])

avr = [sum(x)//len(x) for x in zip(*pixel)]

colors = dict(zip(['red','green','blue'],[i for i in avr]))
print(max(colors))
```

P.S. I use pillow module there. Helped than I could, also new to python